# How to have dynamic targets in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Take a look at this Makefile down below.

```
compose:
    docker-compose up myapp

compose-shell:
    docker-compose run myapp /bin/bash

compose-shellplus:
    docker-compose run myapp make shell

compose-test:
    docker-compose run myapp make test

compose-migrate:
    docker-compose run myapp make migrate

compose-load:
    docker-compose run myapp make load

compose-export:
    docker-compose run myapp make export

compose-flush:
    docker-compose run myapp make flush

# run tests
test:
    python manage.py test --settings=$(PROJECT_SETTINGS)

# install depedencies (and virtualenv for linux)
install:
ifndef WIN
    -virtualenv -p python3 .venv
endif
    pip install -r requirements.txt

# handle django migrations
migrate:
    python manage.py makemigrations --settings=$(PROJECT_SETTINGS)
    python manage.py migrate --settings=$(PROJECT_SETTINGS)

# handle statics
static:
    python manage.py collectstatic --settings=$(PROJECT_SETTINGS)

shell:
    python manage.py shell_plus --settings=$(PROJECT_SETTINGS)

load:
    python manage.py loaddata db.json --settings=${PROJECT_SETTINGS}

export:
    python manage.py dumpdata --indent 2 --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e sessions -e admin -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission  > db.json --settings=${PROJECT_SETTINGS}

flush:
    python manage.py sqlflush --settings=${PROJECT_SETTINGS}
```

Is there's more efficient way of doing this?

For example:

```
compose-${target_name_after_dash}:
    docker-compose run myapp make ${target_name_after_dash}
```

Comment: Why this question been minused? I've asked very constructively what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's always best to try to find the answer in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) before posting on SO.  This is one of the most basic things you can do with GNU make.

Use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html):

```
compose-%:
        docker-compose run myapp make $*
```

Comment: And I've been searching in docs, but I couldn't even form keywords needed for search. If this is duplicate you can vote for close it then.

Comment: Do you have any issues if you have any directory with the same pattern eg. `compose-one/`?

Comment: You will have issues if you try to build a target where there's a directory by that name, because make considers that the target exists: since there are no prerequisites of the target its existence is enough to tell make that it's up to date so make won't try to run the recipe.  Look up "phony targets" to see how to manage this.